# Good books on STLF (Short-term Load Forecast)

Tags: forecasting, references

May I get some of your recommendations on this subset of the more general time series forecasting class of problems?

The reason I need your help is that there's a big number of books that do not address this interesting part of the forecasting problem.

Some of the particularities of STLF (Short-term Load Forecast) is that we do not typically want to resample the data and because of that we have to deal with multiple seasonalities in the data.

I would love to read about what is being done in this set of problems, particularly in book form, since I've been reading papers but because it's very active research, there's not a lot of consensus from what I've been able to gather.

So please, throw me some good book recommendations if you may.

Thank you in advance!